# Alternative to window function in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table in ClickHouse that stores date, tenant_id and some values. I want to check the status of tenant and the status is considered as active if tenant_id has values > 0 for three consecutive days

Table:

```
date      |tenant_id|value
2021-12-28|1681     |2
2021-12-29|1681     |2
2021-12-30|1681     |0
2021-12-31|1681     |2
```

```sql
create table test( date Date, tenant_id UInt64, value Int64) Engine=Memory;

insert into test values 
('2021-12-28',1681,2),('2021-12-29',1681,2),('2021-12-30',1681,0),('2021-12-31',1681,2),
('2021-12-28',1682,2),('2021-12-29',1682,2),('2021-12-30',1682,2),('2021-12-31',1682,2);
```

Expected result:

```
tenant_id|status
1681     |inactive
```

Is it possible to achieve it in ClickHouse without window function as it is restricted in my case?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select tenant_id, 
if (
     arrayExists(k -> length(k)>=3,       -- return 1 if exists array with length >= 3
        arraySplit( j -> j.2 <=0,         -- split array if value <= 0 
           arraySort( i -> i.1,           -- sort array by date
               groupArray((date, value))  -- gather all rows of tenant into array 
           ) 
        )
    ), 'active', 'inactive') status
from test 
group by tenant_id

┌─tenant_id─┬─status───┐
│      1682 │ active   │
│      1681 │ inactive │
└───────────┴──────────┘
```